# How to derive the gradient for SSE cost function in Adaline?

Tags: machine-learning, mathematica

I started learning machine learning and have some troubles in understanding derive rules for the gradient of cost function in particular I can't understand how sum(wjxj) transformed to -xj. I tried to google a detailed breakdown explanation but everywhere the same. I know that it pretty simple for mathematicians for those who hasn't met this for quite long time it's a problem.
[image]

[image]

Could someone explain or/and give links to some resources regarding that.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just wrote the first few terms on a sheet of paper and understood it.
All other terms exept

w<sup>(i)</sup><sub>j</sub> * x<sup>(i)</sup><sub>j</sub>

are constant and thus derive to 0.

The

w<sup>(i)</sup><sub>j</sub> * x<sup>(i)</sup><sub>j</sub>

derives to

x<sup>(i)</sup><sub>j</sub>